# pandas & excel: keeping trailing zero in number stored as string

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a small Excel spreadsheet I'm reading in a Python script using the pandas package.  There is a column with what can look like a number (such as "1.10") that's stored as string and when I access the cell in the Python script, it's extracted as a float and the trailing zero is not present:

```
 0 Section    float  1.1
 0 Text       str    One
 1 Section    float  1.2
 1 Text       str    Two
 2 Section    float  1.3
 2 Text       str    Three
 3 Section    float  1.4
 3 Text       str    Four
 4 Section    float  1.5
 4 Text       str    Five
 5 Section    float  1.6
 5 Text       str    Six
 6 Section    float  1.7
 6 Text       str    Seven
 7 Section    float  1.8
 7 Text       str    Eight
 8 Section    float  1.9
 8 Text       str    Nine
 9 Section    float  1.1
 9 Text       str    Ten
10 Section    float  1.11
10 Text       str    Eleven
```

I created [a gist with a small Python script and Excel spreadsheet](https://gist.github.com/pfuntner/760601827b5f26aad4c4198db70b0cce) to illustrate the problem.

Does anyone know how to extract this type of cell as a string and retain the trailing blanks?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/numbers-as-strings.xlsx', dtype={'Section': str})
```

Output:

```
   Section    Text
0      1.1     One
1      1.2     Two
2      1.3   Three
3      1.4    Four
4      1.5    Five
5      1.6     Six
6      1.7   Seven
7      1.8   Eight
8      1.9    Nine
9     1.10     Ten
10    1.11  Eleven
```

Comment: Wow, that looks super easy.  I guess I was making life hard for myself!

Comment: As I look further, this isn't really better.  Now both "1.1" comes out as "1.10" too.  I want to keep "1.1" and "1.10" unique.